# using regular expression to split string in python

Tags: python, regex

I use

`re.compile(r"(.+?)\1+").findall('44442(2)2(2)44')`

can get

```
['4','2(2)','4']
```

, but how can I get

```
['4444','2(2)2(2)','44']
```

by using regular expression?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No change to your pattern needed. Just need to use to right function for the job. `re.findall` will return a list of groups if there are capturing groups in the pattern. To get the entire match, use [re.finditer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer) instead, so that you can [extract the full match](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match.group) from each actual match object.

```
pattern = re.compile(r"(.+?)\1+")
[match.group(0) for match in pattern.finditer('44442(2)2(2)44')]
```

Comment: Ooo, even better. Learn something every day :D

Answer (score 3):

With minimal change to OP's regular expression:

```
[m[0] for m in re.compile(r"((.+?)\2+)").findall('44442(2)2(2)44')]
```

`findall` will give you the full match if there are no groups, or groups if there are some. So given that you *need* groups for your regexp to work, we simply add another group to encompass the full match, and extract it afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
[i[0] for i in re.findall(r'((\d)(?:[()]*\2*[()]*)*)', s)]
```

Here the Regex is:

```
((\d)(?:[()]*\2*[()]*)*)
```

which will output a list of tuples containing the two captured groups, and we are only interest din the first one hence `i[0]`.

**Example:**

```
In [15]: s
Out[15]: '44442(2)2(2)44'

In [16]: [i[0] for i in re.findall(r'((\d)(?:[()]*\2*[()]*)*)', s)]
Out[16]: ['4444', '2(2)2(2)', '44']
```